# Tkinter alternating displaying an image and text

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a flashcards quiz game in python 2.7 with Tkinter. The general idea is to display a question with no answer, then to add a display of the answer, then to place a new question and erase the answer, and repeat... Sometimes the answer to a question is an image, and sometimes it is text. I want to be able to alternate between showing nothing, showing an image, showing nothing, and showing text. Showing images only, or text only, or images after text works fine. It is showing text after images that does not work for me.

Here is the pertinent part of my code (where a latex string is converted to an image):

```
self.answer = tk.Label(master, text = '')
self.answer.pack()
# stuff stuff stuff

qtxt = self.last_question['A']
if self.last_question['type'] == 'flash-latex':
    sympy.preview(qtxt, viewer='file', filename='qtemp.jpg', euler=False)
    image = Image.open('qtemp.jpg')
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    self.answer.image = photo
    self.answer.config(image = photo)
    self.answer.pack()
else:
    self.answer.config(text = qtxt)
```

Where `master = Tk()`.
The error I get if I try to display text after an image is:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1486, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "game.py", line 65, in next_frame
    self.answer.config(image = None, text = qtxt)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1271, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1262, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist
```

Here is my full code: http://pastebin.com/raw/SdS2fRHJ
Note that some questions with a similar error message to mine on SO had multiple `Tk()` calls, which is not the case here.

I am using `self.label_instance.config(opts)` instead of creating new `tk.Label`s because I don't want the elements in the window to move around.

p.s. I have a suspicion that some reference to the image needs to be erased, or is being prematurely erased, but I am not sure...

p.p.s. I can solve the problem by never trying to display text after an image, i.e. by having two Labels for answers, one for images, and one for text, and displaying a blank image when no image is needed. But, I am curious if this problem is actually fixable (using the same label to display an image, then text, then an image, etc.), or if my workaround is as clean as it gets.

Comment: Change the line after `else` to: `self.answer.config(text = qtxt, image=None)`

Comment: Sorry, nope, still the same error

Comment: I want to test your code but I do not know how you installed this mysterious `parse_notes` library

Comment: My b, parse_notes is here: http://pastebin.com/raw/1a8H4bVf and test.md is here: http://pastebin.com/raw/9RaZ3wSD . Thank you for your help!

Comment: I never did figure out how to reuse a `tk.Label` to display an image and then text. I settled on having multiple `tk.Label`s, some dedicated to displaying images only and others to displaying text only. The project code ended up here: https://github.com/ilyakava/tkflashcards